# Как изменить яркость экрана в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, настройка, windows-8, экран

Делаю скрипт который в зависимости от времени суток будет автоматически настраивать яркость, чтобы глаза не болели. У меня по сути всё есть, осталось только выяснить как изменить яркость экрана.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/screen-brightness-control/ (прмеры кода там есть)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#импорт библиотеки 
import screen_brightness_control as sbc

#установка яркости
sbc.set_brightness(50)
```